# How to create a column based on conditions with rows

Tags: r, case-when, tibble

I have the following problem:

```
Shared_ID<-c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5)
Individual_ID<-c(11,12,13,21,22,23,31,32,33,41,42,43,51,52,53)
Individual_Con<-c(1,2,3,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,2,1)

table<-tibble(Shared_ID,Individual_ID,Individual_Con)
table
```

what I'm looking for is a way to make a new column called **Shared_Con** where: for each Shared_ID shows a number based on the following:

```
Individual_Con==1 ~ 1
Individual_Con==2 ~ 2
Individual_Con==3 ~ 3
any combination of Individual_Con ~ 4
```

For me this means that if **all the Individual_Con within a Shared_ID are x.e equal to 1, then Shared_Con will be 1**, and the last case is **if there are at least 2 different Individual_Con per Shared_ID then Shared_Con will be 4**

This is my desire result:

```
# A tibble: 15 x 4
   Shared_ID Individual_ID Individual_Con Shared_Con
       <dbl>         <dbl>          <dbl>      <dbl>
 1         1            11              1          4
 2         1            12              2          4
 3         1            13              3          4
 4         2            21              1          1
 5         2            22              1          1
 6         2            23              1          1
 7         3            31              2          2
 8         3            32              2          2
 9         3            33              2          2
10         4            41              3          3
11         4            42              3          3
12         4            43              3          3
13         5            51              3          4
14         5            52              2          4
15         5            53              1          4
```

How can I make this easily? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: For Share_ID == 1 there are only 3 combinations in Individual_Con so should not Shared_Con be 3 instead of 4?

Comment: No, 1 means all Individual_Con==1 .... up to 3, 4 means at least 2 different Individual_Con per Shared_ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do a group by 'Shared_ID', check whether the number of distinct elements in 'Individual_Con' are greater than 1 then return 4 or else return the Individual_Con

```
library(dplyr)
table %>%
     group_by(Shared_ID) %>%
     mutate(Shared_Con = if(n_distinct(Individual_Con) > 1) 4 else Individual_Con)
# A tibble: 15 x 4
# Groups:   Shared_ID [5]
#   Shared_ID Individual_ID Individual_Con Shared_Con
#       <dbl>         <dbl>          <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1         1            11              1          4
# 2         1            12              2          4
# 3         1            13              3          4
# 4         2            21              1          1
# 5         2            22              1          1
# 6         2            23              1          1
# 7         3            31              2          2
# 8         3            32              2          2
# 9         3            33              2          2
#10         4            41              3          3
#11         4            42              3          3
#12         4            43              3          3
#13         5            51              3          4
#14         5            52              2          4
#15         5            53              1          4
```

Comment: This worked just fine and I'll mark it as Answer, but is there a way to save that new column into the table and not just print it?

Comment: @RaúlValentínFonseca you can do assignment `table <- table %>% group_by(...`